# Confused by blood pressure terms

Tags: blood-pressure

I'm doing some research into digital blood pressure monitors and I have come across some terms that I could use a hand with, thanks

1. Mean pressure
2. Empirical statistical oscillometric parameters
3. Systolic pressure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*According to this book (freely available on NCBI bookshelf: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK268/) Clinical Methods: The History, Physical, and Laboratory Examinations. 3rd edition.
Chapter 16: Blood Pressure by Walter A. Brzezinski.*

**Systolic blood (SBP)** pressure corresponds to the maximum blood pressure during contraction of the ventricles

**Diastolic pressure (DBP)** is the minimum pressure recorded just prior to the next contraction.

**The mean arterial pressure (MAP)** is calculated by the formula:
MAP = (2DBP+SBP)/3

The mean arterial pressure is used to calculate overall blood flow and provides a good indication of the delivery of nutrients to the various organs.
It is also a good indicator of perfusion pressure (ΔP).

**Oscillometric methods** are used in automated BP monitors to calculate BP [1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25570365)

> Oscillometry is perhaps the most popular, non-invasive and automatic
> blood pressure (BP) measurement method. This method employs
> an inflatable arm cuff with a pressure sensor inside it. The measured
> cuff pressure not only rises and falls with cuff inflation and
> deflation but also shows tiny oscillations indicating the pulsatile
> blood volume (BV) in the artery. The amplitude of these oscillations
> varies with the applied cuff pressure, as the arterial stiffness is
> nonlinear. **BP values are then estimated from the oscillometric cuff
> pressure waveform using population-based methods such as fixed-ratios.**

So those "***empirical statistical oscillometric parameters***" are probably population-based parameters which are used to calculate and interpret the oscillations arrising during the measuring of the BP.

*Sources:*

1. Liu J, Cheng H, Chen C-H, Sung S-H, Hahn J-O, Mukkamala R. Model-Based Oscillometric Blood Pressure Measurement: Preliminary Validation in Humans. Conference proceedings : Annual International Conference of the IEEE Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society IEEE Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society Annual Conference. 2014;2014:1961-1964. doi:10.1109/EMBC.2014.6943997.